# Delete Specific file type in bulk

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input, delete-file

I need to delete files with a specific extension and the script I have does that but it does it one by one but not in bulk and I have honestly been very confused on how to complete this can I get some help on this please the script below:

```
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('path'):
    for xml in filenames:
        if xml.lower().endswith('.xml'):
            if input('remove exisiting xml files? y/n: ') == "y":
                os.remove(os.path.join(root, XML))
                print('the file has been deleted succesfully')
        else:
            print('the file has not been deleted')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a modification to your script, so you don't have to type 'y' for each file you can do the following:

```
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('path'):
    for xml in filenames:
        if xml.lower().endswith('.xml'):
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, XML))
```

If you do this, be aware that the script will now delete any file ending in .xml